# validación cabeceras de una hoja laravel excel

Tags: laravel-5, excel, validación, importación, laravel-excel

favor me ayudan con el siguiente problema que se me presento, estoy realizando la importación de un excel con el paquete laravel excel, y estoy realzando la importación de una planilla pero solo importando los datos que se encuentran en una hoja que contiene llamada "Base", esto lo estoy haciendo de esta forma desde el controlador

```
$import = new PayrollImport();
$import->onlySheets('Base');
Excel::import($import, $file);
```

Y en el archivo de importacion "PayrollImport" tengo lo siguiente

```
class PayrollImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    use WithConditionalSheets;

    public function conditionalSheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Base' => new FirstSheetImport(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Eso anterior me funciona y selecciona la segunda hora llamada "Base" y la leo desde mi importador con la siguiente funcion

```
class FirstSheetImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            // Mi logica de lectura e insercion
        }
    }

    // Reglas de validacion cabecera
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '2.0'   => 'in:codigo',
            '2.1'   => 'in:nombre',
            '2.2'   => 'in:rut',
            '2.3'   => 'in:fecha_ing',
            '2.4'   => 'in:fecha_ret',
            '2.5'   => 'in:cod',
            '2.171' => 'in:total_cost_company'
        ];
    }
}
```

El asunto es que mi función "rules" solo esta validando las cabeceras de la primera hoja de mi planilla excel, y yo realmente necesito validar las cabeceras de mi segunda hoja llamada "Base".
¿ Como puedo realizar esta validación?